# How can I use the performance script of kafka with text?

Tags: linux, load, performance-testing, apache-kafka

I have this command: `./bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --broker-list=localhost:9092 --messages 10000000 --topic test --threads 10 --message-size 1000 --batch-size 100 --compression-codec 1`

But I would like to run that but with text, that one just send empty messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an **Performance Tool** provided by **KAFKA** which helps you to produce number of messages, size of messages and batch size as per your requirement but with one condition that the data will be generated in the form of **BYTE ARRAY**.

If you wish to produce message as per your customization then you can write your own **custom producer** because this tool is not going help you with that.